# Use raw HTML Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I need to format the contents of a select box with css.  That can't be done with a standard select, of course, so I've tried to implement Select2 to do it.

The basic format of my html is as follows

```
<select>
    <option>
        <span class="a">first</span>
        <span class="b">second</span>
    </option>
    <option>
        <span class="a">first</span>
        <span class="b">second</span>
    </option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately select2 strips the html out of the option.

Also, I'm using AngularJS to actually populate the fields.  That may make a difference.  I have tried using UI-Select library, but it has too many bugs that are still unresolved.

Comment: I've looked through the docs without much success.  Would you please provide a link to how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

`<option>` elements are not allowed to have any children other than plain text nodes.

- See: [It is bad to put <span /> tags inside <option /> tags, only for string manipulation not styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat)

That said, Select2 provides options for templating, which allows you to wrap or otherwise alter the values before they are displayed. I suggest reading through the documentation:

- **Templating**: http://select2.github.io/select2/#templating

Here's the example from the above link:

```
function format(state) {
    if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
    return "<img class='flag' src='images/flags/" + state.id.toLowerCase() + ".png'/>" + state.text;
}
$("#e4").select2({
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

Here's a question with a few answers that will help you integrate it into your AngularJS app:

- [Use select2 plugin in AngularJS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572196/use-select2-plugin-in-angularjs-application)